# Accessing Shiro principal collection data from thymleaf

Tags: thymeleaf, shiro

Using Shiro spring boot starter 1.4.0 in Spring boot application and can't figure out how i can extract shiro principalCollection data into my thymeleaf templates to use in other expressions etc...

I store some lightweight user data in shiro and wanted to display a custom message using current users first name and last login time

for example:

```
<p th:text="#{welcome.lastlogin.message(${???.firstName},${???.lastLoginTime})}">..Hello, user, how are you today?..</p>
```

I did dump the session attribute to see what shiro is storing the principals as and i see this in session:

org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DefaultSubjectContext_PRINCIPALS_SESSION_KEY = john.doe@somewhere.com,{userID=1,firstName=John, lastName=Doe, loginAttempts=0, lastLoginTime=Mon Jan 22 09:30:47 EST 2018}

My code uses a HashMap and adds it to the principals...

Is this even possible?

edit: I guess the other option is simply not use shiro principalCollection for this purpose and put my own object in session and use it from thymeleaf instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [thymeleaf-extras-shiro](https://github.com/theborakompanioni/thymeleaf-extras-shiro), It might do exactly what you are looking for. Otherwise, I'm guessing you would need to use `principalCollection.getPrimaryPrincipal()`

Comment: Hi Brian... thanks for the info. I'm already using that library, which works great.. But I guess the issue i was having is how i could inject the taglib values into various other thymeleaf expressions and fragments? For instance, injecting the shiro:principal into a message key lookup as a parameter?

Comment: I'm not sure on that one, you may want to reach out to the author.  In a pinch, you could always add an object to the Thymeleaf context.

Comment: Thanks Brian.. that is what i did. I leaned out my shiro principals and used a few entries in the principal collection (userid, login time, attempts etc) and created my own session object containing lightweight user data like firstname, email etc... which i add to session and reference in thymeleaf using $session)